# Spark DataFrame AnalysisException

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to select few columns from a dataframe (scala language).
The problem is, I am not able to put all columns into a single string and pass to the select function of the DataFrame. I tried the following but its not working:

```
scala> val str1 = "sum(\"bal1\")/100,"
str1: String = sum("bal1")/100,

scala> val str2 = "sum(\"bal12\")/100,"
str1: String = sum("bal2")/100,

scala> val str3 = str1.concat(str2)
str3: String = sum("bal1")/100,sum("bal2")/100

peopleDataFrame.select(str3).show // Throws AnalysisException as mentioned below

scala> peopleDataFrame.select(str3).show
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'sum("bal1")/100,sum("bal2")/100' given input columns name, bal1, bal2;
```

## Full Code Snippet:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val people = sc.textFile("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/sekar/1.txt")
val schemaString = "name,bal1,bal2"
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType,StructField,IntegerType};
val schema =
  StructType(
    schemaString.split(",").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, IntegerType, true)))
val rowRDD = people.map(_.split(",")).map(p => Row(p(0).toString, p(1).toInt, p(2).toInt))  
val peopleDataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)

scala> val str1 = "sum(\"bal1\")/100,"
str1: String = sum("bal1")/100,

scala> val str2 = "sum(\"bal12\")/100,"
str1: String = sum("bal2")/100,

scala> val str3 = str1.concat(str2)
str3: String = sum("bal1")/100,sum("bal2")/100

peopleDataFrame.select(str3).show
```

str3 is resolving properly to 'sum("bal1")/100,sum("bal2")/100'. Please let me know how to resolve the AnalysiseException.

Please let me know if more information is required. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a sample of your data and the desired output ? It's no very clear what you are doing !

Answer (score 0):

Spark API does not support passing multiple expressions at once in the same string.

Also, some parts of the input should be changed as well:

- 'select' method is working with the Spark API types, not strings. Consider 'selectExpr' instead.
- No need to wrap the column names in double quotes.

---

That said, the following can be done in at least two different ways:

**1)** Replacing 'select' with 'selectExpr' method, and passing each projection separately.
For Example:

```
peopleDataFrame.selectExpr("sum(bal1) / 100", "sum(bal2) / 100").show
```

See selectExpr method from DataFrame API for more information:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

**2)** Registering data frame as a temp table, and execution SQL directly (this may be useful if projections are coming from outside)

```
peopleDataFrame.registerTempTable("peopleDataFrame")
sqlContext.sql("SELECT sum(bal1) / 100, sum(bal2) / 100 FROM peopleDataFrame").show()
```